# React Pwa IOS - On second launch the app stuck on loading

Tags: ios, reactjs, .net-core, progressive-web-apps

So I have a PWA app, Backend is dotnetcore 2.2, front end is react, and it’s running on raspberry pi 3.

The app is working on chrome and safari, the problem starts when I’m adding the Pwa to the home screen in my iPhone X 13.2, at the first launch it works correctly (Getting data from the backend api), but when I’m closing the Pwa and launch it again, it stuck on loading(Show loading circle until data is loaded).

On my mini iPad iOS 11 works find, in android it works fine.

Can anyone direct me on how to debug this problem without Mac or and pointers to look for?